# Complete Newbie at Laravel, wondering if I'm using models correctly

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

So I've got three models, "Incomplete", "User", and "Collaboration". They are related with foreign keys as such:

```
Collaboration->incomplete_id
incomplete_id->Incomplete
Incomplete->user_id
user_id->User
```

If I want to get the email of a user for a Collaboration model I have the following code

```
User::find(Incomplete::find($collab->incomplete_id)->user_id)->email);
```

I feel like this is wrong as I'm not joining any tables but  I don't want to break out of mvc and call straight up SQL from the controller. Basically I'm curious how I could do this correctly.

**Collaboration Model**

```
class Collaboration extends Eloquent{
//Set the database to connect to as form d
protected $connection = 'formd';

//Set the table for the model to incomplets
protected $table = 'collaborations';

//Set the fillable columns
protected $fillable = array('incompid', 'link', 'shareFlag');


private $rules = array(
    'link'=>'required|unique:collaborations|size:56',
    'incompid'=>'required|integer'

);

private $errors;

public function validate($data)
{
    // make a new validator object
    $v = Validator::make($data, $this->rules);

    // check for failure
    if ($v->fails())
    {
        // set errors and return false
        $this->errors = $v->errors();
        return false;
    }

    // validation pass
    return true;
}

public function errors()
{
    return $this->errors;
}

public function getId(){
    return $this->getKey();
}

public function incomplete(){
    return $this->hasOne('Incomplete');
}   

}
```

**Incomplete Model**

```
class Incomplete extends Eloquent{
//Set the database to connect to as form d
protected $connection = 'formd';

//Set the table for the model to incomplets
protected $table = 'incompletes';

//Set the fillable columns
protected $fillable = array('name', 'data', 'userid');


private $rules = array(
    'name' => 'required|min:3',
    'data' => 'required'

);

  private $errors;

public function validate($data)
{
    // make a new validator object
    $v = Validator::make($data, $this->rules);

    // check for failure
    if ($v->fails())
    {
        // set errors and return false
        $this->errors = $v->errors();
        return false;
    }

    // validation pass
    return true;
}

public function errors()
{
    return $this->errors;
}

public function getId(){
    return $this->getKey();
}

public function getData(){
    return $this->data;
}

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}


public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne('User');
}   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eloquents relations:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

```
class Collaboration extends Eloquent {

    public function incomplete()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Incomplete', 'incomplete_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

You can then get the data from the incomplete record by doing:

```
$collab->incomplete->user_id
```

Comment: I have the functions in my model but when I try to run $collab->incomplete()->user_id it gives me the following error
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$user_id

Comment: @okawei Post code, please. Also, make sure you are returning the $this->hasOne() -- I made that mistake and it took me a long time to realise.

Comment: @okawei do it like this instead: `$collab->incomplete->user_id` . calling incomplete() returns the relation and not the resulting object. To do it the way you were trying to, you'd have to do `$collab->incomplete()->first()->user_id`

Comment: @ErinDrummond Just noticed that, was about to say the same thing :)

Comment: Got it! @Jono20201 I did have to switch the hasOne arguments though so it was hasOne('Incomplete', 'id', 'incomplete_id')

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess a follow up question would be is this the most optimized way of doing things?  It still feels dirty coming from solely writing straight up sql

Comment: yes it is. using hasOne/hasMany etc caches the relation so calling it multiple times does not incur the cost of multiple database calls. it also allows you to access relations as though they were simply properties. additionally, it handles the "join" logic for you (although Laravel favours multiple SELECTs over a JOIN)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, use a relation on your models:

```
class Collaboration extends Eloquent {

public function incomplete()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Incomplete', 'incomplete_id');
}}
```

And

```
class Incomplete extends Eloquent {

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}}
```

Then, do this:

```
Collaboration::find($id)->incomplete()->user()->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you'll have to update parts of your model class

```
    Class Collaboration extends Eloquent{
      protected function incomplete(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Incomplete');
      } 
    }
    Class Incomplete extends Eloquent{
      protected function collaboration(){
        return $this->hasOne('Collaboration');
      }
      protected function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
      }
    }
    Class User extends Eloquent(){
      protected function incomplete(){
        return $this->hasOne('Incomplete');
      }
    }
```

Then inorder to get what your want, here is the query

```
Collaboration::find($id)->incomplete()->user()->email;
```